# Without biological research, would be people ever able to come to an idea of neural networks?

Tags: biology, computers, scientific-development

Without biology, would people come to an idea of computer neural nets?

Comment: It seems likely to me that this concept could be invented without biological research once computer science itself was sufficiently advanced. However, it would be so far in the future that it might not even be worthwhile, other advancements could prove superior by that point (they might have god-like computing by then). Note this is highly speculative, and so I'll leave it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sure, why not? In IT people have envisioned structures like B-Trees that have no equivalent in nature. They just fit a specific need. Neural networks would be the same.

Comment: This is an open-ended discussion question; there is no problem to solve.

Comment: We call them 'neural networks; only because they have some vague resemblance to biology, not because they mimic biology. The concept behind neural networks has nothing to do with biology,

Comment: The name "neural network" was hijacked from biology and applied to what used to be called [perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) and [group method of data handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_method_of_data_handling) algorithms in the mid-1960s. The intention was to raise warm and fuzzy feelings in the minds of the bureaucrats who approved research grants. The computer kind of neural networks were never intended to work like the biological kind, and they still don't.